Visual Studio 2022 Properties window not displaying Build options menu option

As you can see, the menu item Build is not displayed for any of my projects on VS 2022 version 17.9.0 on my Windows 11 machine.
The projects were all copied from my Windows 10 machine to my Windows 11 machine some time ago. The Build menu selection is still displayed on the Windows 10 machine.
The projects build in Debug mode but not Release mode and I need to change an option that is normally selectable in the Build menu.

Have you opened Visual Studio Installer and repaired you Visual Studio installation?

It seems that you blocked out some information. For Configuration and Platform are the values N/A, or did you modify them in the image prior to posting? If you didn't modify the values in the image, in the VS menu, click Build => Configuration Manager to ensure that everything is setup correctly.  This information is in the project's *.csproj file which you can view with Notepad. You may also verify Tools => Options... => NuGet Package Manager => General => Default package management format. Ensure that it matches the value on your other computer.

It appears that the latest version of Visual Studio is 17.9.6. I recommend upgrading to the latest version before you spend too much time troubleshooting the issue. See Visual Studio 2022 Release Notes for more information.

@user246821 Thanks mate. Repairing did the trick.
